# Call Action in Controller when an Option of a Select-Tag is selected

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

For a real-estate website i am using options within a select-tag for the User to choose the order in which the properties are shown. I want to order them as soon as one option is selected. I already have a Controller which can handle the sorting so all i really need is a way to call the controller with the value im getting from the DropDownMenu.

I found several solutions using JQuery but i was wondering if theres also a way using just ASP.NET. Basically something like: `<select asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="MyAction">`

Also a lot of people are using `@Html.DropDownList(...)` instead of a select-tag. Any reasons for that?

My select tag currently looks like this (just in case it helps)

```
<select class="form-input select-filter">
    <option value="price_low_to_high">Price Low to High</option>
    <option value="price_high_to_low">Price High to Low</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you show us more code on your attempt. This can be done using `Jquery` and `AJAX` to send your value to your `Controller` method and get a response back. Based on that response, you can manipulate the DOM to show your result.

Comment: ok so basically it can only be done using `Jquery` or `Ajax`? If thats the case i already know how to proceed. Thanks a lot @RahulSharma